# Cannot Share Document With External User

Tags: permissions, external-users

We have an Office 365 Business Premium plan that I've been learning as I go along setting it up. I'm in the process of setting up SharePoint sites and folders to store our shared information by department to migrate it from our on-site NAS. I've created a private folder for our Tech department that I've placed some documents in and one of the documents I want to share with an external user to collaborate on.

I've tried the regular "Share" button on the document but the "Anyone" option is greyed out. I tried to specify to share with specific people but it just told me that sharing with people outside the organisation isn't permitted. I've gone through all the steps listed [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232), [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85), [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-external-sharing-on-or-off-for-SharePoint-Online-6288296a-b6b7-4ea4-b4ed-c297bf833e30#ID0EAABAAA=Tenant_(global)), and [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-SharePoint-files-or-folders-in-Office-365-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c) and everything looks to be set up fine, all the options say to allow external access if selected. Except I can't.

Is there something I'm missing? Is it because I set the whole site to be private? I would rather not have the site contents accessible by anyone other than the Tech dept. except the files I choose to share.